# Can a virus be executed by reading a file using System.IO libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, virus

I have a website that is accepting what (appears to be) CSV files, reading the headers locally in a browser (using HTML5), and then uploading the file to a server.  If the headers are not found, it won't upload.  This will be exposed to the public at some point.

It will never get executed, only read via the System.IO libraries to extract the data rows.  If it can't parse through the CSV, it cancels out.  I can't think of how a virus would ever execute in this scenario.  Am I wrong? Do I need to run a virus scan?

Comment: Any client-side validation can be bypassed..

Comment: that's not really what I'm asking.  I'm asking if the act of reading a file with IO libraries server-side can somehow execute a virus.

Comment: No, you don't need to run a virus scan. It's just a pile of bytes that mean nothing unless executed. Of course, there might be some vulnerability in .Net or a library that you are using that might make it possible to send up a malformed document that causes some sort of buffer overflow, but in general, the .net platform protects you against such problems (which are the preferred deployment method of most virus infections). In your position, I wouldn't even consider virus checking the payloads. Does it parse? Good to go. Otherwise, reject.

Comment: Missing a lot of detail, but seems  like *reading the headers locally in a browser (using HTML5),* could be problematic